# A question about the dimension theory of Hilbert space.

Tags: general-topology

Let $H$ be a real, separable and infinite dimensional Hilbert space. If $S$ is any subset of $H$ that disconnects $H$, is $S$ necessarily infinite dimensional? I cannot find any discussion of this in the literature, although I am pretty sure the answer must be "yes".

Comment: What do you mean that S disconnects H, and also how do you define the dimension of a subset?

Comment: @user25959 $H\setminus S$ is not connected.

Comment: Yes. This holds because the space is strongly infinite-dimensional. Look for that notion in the literature.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma: Thanks for the explanation. It would be nice if a proof of the finite dimensional version of this theorem-where the dimension of H is n and the dimension of S has to be at least n-1 -could be easily transformed into a proof of the infinite dimensional version.